# magento memcached is not caching files

Tags: magento, memcached

Problem:
 
Files are not being cached using memcached while i have refresh all cache from `magento admin`.
I have installed memcached on magento
and its stats is like below and configuration done on local.xml file which is mentioned below.
please some body help to make it working.
I have doubt that something may have wrong on `configuration` or `memcached`.

```
stats
STAT pid 8897
STAT uptime 149352
STAT time 1331275345
STAT version 1.4.6
STAT libevent 2.0.17-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 0.026995
STAT rusage_system 0.030995
STAT curr_connections 5
STAT total_connections 8
STAT connection_structures 7
STAT cmd_get 0
STAT cmd_set 0
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT get_hits 0
STAT get_misses 0
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 21
STAT bytes_written 1628
STAT limit_maxbytes 536870912
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 0
STAT bytes 0
STAT curr_items 0
STAT total_items 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 0
```

and i have configured the `app/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
<global>
    <cache>
        <backend>memcached</backend><!-- apc / memcached / empty=file -->
        <memcached><!-- memcached cache backend related config -->
        <servers><!-- any number of server nodes can be included -->
            <server>
                <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                <port><![CDATA[11211]]></port>
                <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
            </server>
        </servers>
        <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
        <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
        <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
        <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
        <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[lb-]]></file_name_prefix>
        </memcached>
    </cache>

    <install>
        <date><![CDATA[Fri, 11 Nov 2011 16:02:21 +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
        <key><![CDATA[admin]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[username]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[dbnam]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
    </resources>
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, be sure to check that the Memcache daemon is actually running

```
ps ax | grep memcache
```

Then, make sure that you have actually installed the PHP extension

Search within the document for Memcache to make sure it is actually loaded.

These are the 2 only reasons that Memcache would not be working.

To verify if Memcache is in use is very simple.

1. Disable all caches in the Magento admin (System > Cache Management).
2. Click "Flush cache storage"
3. Enable all caches

Then empty the content of the

```
./var/cache/*
```

directory, then reload a page in the frontend and observe the contents of the above directory. If it remains empty, Memcache is being used.

See http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/what-is-memcache-actually-caching-in-magento/

Answer (score 2):

take reference the following settings :

```
    <config>
    <global>
        <session_save><![CDATA[]]></session_save> <!-- db / memcache / empty=files -->
        <session_save_path><![CDATA[]]></session_save_path><!-- e.g. for memcache session save handler tcp://10.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10 -->
        <session_cache_limiter><![CDATA[]]></session_cache_limiter><!-- see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php#82174 for possible values -->
        <cache>
            <backend></backend><!-- apc / memcached / xcache / empty=file -->
            <slow_backend></slow_backend> <!-- database / file (default) - used for 2 levels cache setup, necessary for all shared memory storages -->
            <memcached><!-- memcached cache backend related config -->
                <servers><!-- any number of server nodes can be included -->
                    <server>
                        <host><![CDATA[]]></host>
                        <port><![CDATA[]]></port>
                        <persistent><![CDATA[]]></persistent>
                        <weight><![CDATA[]]></weight>
                        <timeout><![CDATA[]]></timeout>
                        <retry_interval><![CDATA[]]></retry_interval>
                        <status><![CDATA[]]></status>
                    </server>
                </servers>
                <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
                <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
                <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
                <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
                <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
            </memcached>
        </cache>
    </global>
</config>
```

Also, make sure PHP `memcache.ini` file has been configured properly like below :

```
$ aptitude install php5-memcache
$ aptitude install memcached

extension=memcache.so

[memcache]  
memcache.dbpath="/var/lib/memcache"  
memcache.maxreclevel=0  
memcache.maxfiles=0  
memcache.archivememlim=0  
memcache.maxfilesize=0  
memcache.maxratio=0  

;Use memcache as a session handler  
session.save_handler=memcache  

;Defines server urls to use for session storage  
session.save_path="tcp://localhost:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Magento you are using, there will be some changes in the local.xml options for caching. In never versions you should define both the backend and the slow_backend and configure Memcache as a backend.

Something along these lines might help:

```
<cache>
<slow_backend></slow_backend> 
<fast_backend>memcached</fast_backend>
<fast_backend_options>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <host>127.0.0.1</host>
      <port>11211</port>
      <persistent>1</persistent>
    </server>
  </servers>
</fast_backend_options>

<backend>memcached</backend>
<memcached>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <host>127.0.0.1</host>
      <port>11211</port>
      <persistent>1</persistent>
    </server>
  </servers>
</memcached>
</cache>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem the other day. If I'm remembering correctly it's caused by not leaving file_name_prefix blank (or `<![CDATA[]]>`)